# Ошибка sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, бот, telebot

Ошибка в строке user_id = message.from_user.id(я до этого кода подключил токен)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"hello I'm bot po zametkah", reply_markup=keyboard1)
       user_id = message.from_user.id
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: user_id
 
[Program finished]
```

Comment: Не работает(у меня подключена бд).

Comment: Я думаю, вы умеете пользоваться переводчиком?=) Там ведь написано - `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: user_id` Это означает, что в вашей созданной таблице в базе данных не существует такой колонки. Для наглядности - откройте созданный файл таблицы `sqlite` с помощью программы SQLiteStudio и посмотрите на структуру своей таблицы

Answer (score -1):

для получения ID пользователя можно при вводе команды /start получать его ID так:

`user = message.chat.id`

Вот пример:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты начал работу с ботом!')
    user = message.chat.id
```